I constantly get the initial value from the reducer
I just started learning redux< redux-toolkit and ran into the problem that my stat from the "Pastime" reducer always returns the initial value, although it works correctly in another functional component.
The reducer
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

type TInitialState = {
    value: number;
}

const initialState: TInitialState = {
    value: 10,
}

const passTimerSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'passTimer',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
     setDefault: state => {
      state.value = 12
    },
    addSeccond: state => {
      state.value -= 1
    }
    },
})

export const { addSeccond, setDefault } = passTimerSlice.actions

export default passTimerSlice.reducer

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(slices.passTimer.setDefault())

    passTimerId = setInterval(() => {
        console.log('passTimer', passTimer)

        if (passTimer <= 0) {
            clearInterval(passTimerId)
            return
        }

        dispatch(slices.passTimer.removeSeccond())
    }, 1000)

    return () => {
        clearInterval(passTimerId) // Clear interval on component unmount
    }
}, [passState])


I will be glad of any hint
I reread the documentation, but I didn't find what my mistake was.

Your useEffect uses the selected passState value as a dependency, so any time the passState value updates, the effect runs again, each time resetting the passState back to 12. We can only really point out the obvious issue, but since it's unclear what you are expecting this code to do, i.e. the expected behavior, it's difficult to make any suggestions to fix/improve the logic. Can you [edit] to clarify the use case and what you are trying to accomplish here?

Also, your action is addSecond but the reducer appears to subtract a second, not sure if this is intentional or not, but it seems incorrect.

he should reset the timer to default, passState and Pastimer are different states, the first one stores who has the move now, the second one has the number of seconds that he has for the move. My problem is that when I set the interval, the pastimer returns its default value to me every second, although it works correctly inside and the time decreases

passState doesn't appear to be a relevant dependency since it's not referenced in the useEffect hook callback. What is passTimer? It's closed over in callback scope so likely will never be a different value. I think you should still [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with so it's clear to readers here what your code is doing and when/why it's doing it.

I solved this problem by putting the tracking of the timerState value change in a separate useEffect
    useEffect(() => {
    console.log(timerState)
    if (timerState <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timerId)
        console.log('time end')
    }
}, [timerState])


Every time your passState changes, you dispatch a slices.passTimer.setDefault() action, so I would assume that you either want an empty dependency array there, or to remove that dispatch.

the passState stores the one who is walking now, and dispatch(slices.pastimer.setDefault()) is needed so that after the owner of the move changes, the timer is reset to the default value

The whole passState, not passState.value or something? Just out of interest, remove it from the dependency array and see what happens - if that fixes it, that passState is changing constantly. Also take a look at the Redux DevTools which actions are being dispatched in what order.

const passState = useAppSelector(state => state.passState.value) this is what my past state of the "owner of the move" looks like, useAppSelector is the same useSelector from react-redux only with an overridden type. If you delete it, the move will not be transmitted. I checked redux WebKit, it works correctly. I fixed this problem by adding a crutch from the additional timerState state change listener, I hope my understanding of redux will improve soon and I will be able to add a more correct answer. But if you are interested in my mistake, I can open a repository for you.
